# run rustup's curl-fetched installer script non-interactively

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to automate stuff which includes installing rust through

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

This is interactive and queries for user-input to choose from i.e. "1" "2" or "3".

Not able to figure out, how to input.

Normally for apt-get, "-y" option try to capture and input for prompt.

Not sure, how it is done for curl.

How can I do this?

Comment: `curl` is not interactive; the script it retrieves is.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To make the installation unatended you can run

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
```

If you are ssh'd you should add the nohup parameter in front

With the `-s` parameter, you set sh to read commands from the standard input, and then you pass the `-y` to auto accept the options

For more info about sh you can see the [man pages](http://man.openbsd.org/sh)

Comment: What is the purpose of the -- before the -y.

Comment: I tried echo -ne '\n' | $(curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh) 
Do you know why it did not work?
My reasoning was $() will execute the curl, sh and will take input from the echo.

Comment: After running the curl request, if I run `cargo build --release` inside a Docker, I'm getting cargo not found. Any specific reason?

Comment: You probably need to source the cargo env first `source $HOME/.cargo/env && cargo build --release`

Comment: Curiously, i was working on this but was noticing that it was hanging near the end of it.  Seems like the tty might have broke, so it isnt letting me continue with the build command.  Curious what is going on.  says: "rush is installed now. Great!...  To configure your current shell, run: ...." but it just hangs thereafter.